# Can I prevent all employees from accessing customer data without being logged (especially IT)

Tags: encryption, web-application, azure

I am hosting a web application and SQL server database on Azure and I would like to ensure that no individual at the company can access customer data without the access being logged. It seems that with all the security options in Azure there is always a way for at least one admin with malicious intent can gain access to keys and anonymously access the data or storage of the data. What option are there to secure the data from access without an audit log?

(This scope of this question does not include the trust in the cloud provider and is specifically only concerned with securing against employees of the technology company)

Comment: Keep in mind that when you run your SQL database on Microsoft's servers, a sufficiently paranoid compliance concept also needs to address the possibility of Microsoft employees accessing your data.

Answer (score 2):

If there's a way to access data without an audit log, secure the credentials required to access it that way and audit their access. Software such as [Vault](https://www.vaultproject.io/) is geared toward this. Physical control of an MFA token such as storing it on a YubiKey and then putting that in a safe place with somebody who doesn't control the password would provide you with dual control.

Comment: @jbferland, thanks for the suggestion. The challenge with that is securing the keys or secrets on the web server itself. The system must at some time access the key vault by itself to decrypt the data. I do not see a mechanism that prevents an admin from pulling the secrets from the server or recording the secrets when they create the server initially. They can impersonate the server and access the keys/data looking like they are the application.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's going to be extremely difficult, if not impossible to do this.

Think about ALL the places where customer data exists, or  can be accessed from:

Production SQL servers.
Development SQL servers.
Backup servers.
Production webservers.
Development webservers.

You probably are already auditing production webservers.  But what about development webservers, and is the audit trail preserved, or does it get blown away when you refresh the environment?

Even then, you'd still need audit trails on both your SQL servers, and backup servers.  This may or may not be even possible depending on what you're using for your SQL server, and for backup.

In essence, auditing all access to data isn't a trivial task because data needs to flow around easily to get work done, and auditing of any access it isn't built into every product.

Comment: "what about development webservers" There shouldn't ever be PII on development webservers. Databases contents should be mocked mercilessly and often. If the database contents were a person, you'd want them to accuse you of harassment for all the mockery.

Comment: @ParthianShot And the world shouldn't contain any SQL injection attacks either, since it's been a well understood problem with known solutions for more than a decade.  The real world is quite different from the way things "should be".

Comment: @SteveSether hit the nail on the head with the real world comment...

Comment: The point about consumer data in fact being stored in non-production databases by plenty of security-sloppy organizations is a good one, certainly. But @Partian Shot's point is certainly correct as well. If you have customer data on non-production systems you have a far more urgent problem than the one the OP asks about.

Comment: @halfinformed Like everything in security, it depends.  Not all customer data is sensitive enough to restrict all access to it to a small amount of people.

Comment: @SteveSether Sure, but the OP is specifically asking about the kind of data which *is* sensitive enough to restrict access, so your point is moot.

Comment: @ParthianShot The real world is far more complex than creating a series of policies and technologies that you think will save you.  It's naive to think that you can somehow control all information and audit it.  Real world test systems almost always have real data in them for legitimate reasons and thinking you can stop this from happening with policies from the security guy isn't realistic.

Comment: Yeah, but your point seems to be "you can't control everything, so don't try to control anything", which is ridiculous. You can make the process of getting customer data off of a given machine really, really annoying if you want to. And when you do that, surprise surprise, people don't use customer data in testing. I've worked in companies that did that, and it worked pretty well. It's relatively easy to make sure the the sysadmins aren't the testers, and make sure that they know they'll be fired if they start giving auth tokens away, so that when the testers ask for data, they get told 'no'.

Comment: @ParthianShot Now you're putting words in my mouth.  The assumption of many security people is policy dictates all, and they have the final say.  The point is, you have to work with people and negotiate solutions that work for everyone.  Otherwise you just become a barrier to be overcome.  "You'll be fired of you do X" is a terrible, terrible policy and an example of a sick culture.  The BOFH attitude in the security world needs to go.

Comment: ""You'll be fired of you do X" is a terrible, terrible policy and an example of a sick culture." Well, what I meant was along the lines of "you'll be fired if you do X without asking your superior first". And I'd argue that some things are on-the-spot fireable offenses. As long as you're clear about what constitutes such an offense from the outset, I don't really see the problem, there. In the same way that being ticketed for speeding on a road with no signs is egregious, but if there are signs, or if you're going 100 in a school zone, it's not a "sick culture".

Comment: Point being, if it's other people's personal information, you have a duty of care. And if you can't live up to that duty of care, that's okay, but you need to be working in a role such that you don't have that duty anymore.

Comment: @ParthianShot A culture where an immediate response is discipline or firing is an example of a culture that doesn't work.  I see this attitude all the time.  You only create an atmosphere of fear, intimidation, and hiding the truth.  You mentioned the police, and laws.  That's the pervasive idea I'm talking about.  Security people shouldn't view themselves as the police, but as team members trying to accomplish goals.